# Which object meshes should I combine?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm currently testing [draw call minimizer](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/2859) and it is working as it should be. It just combines the meshes together so number of draw calls is smaller. I'm just wondering how should I choose which meshes I should combine. I assume that merging everything in the scene isn't a good idea. Should I combine them based on the distance between them(combine only meshes that are close together) or these that share same material? I think that combining meshes that are close together makes sense because there is not too much additional mesh data passed to graphics card(If I would combine everything this might be a problem), but I'm not an expert so I ask you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just read the description... 
This asset is to combine "things" (meshes, textures, materials) that share exactly the same properties.
Means: Are you re-using *the same mesh at different locations* in your game? Combine them!
Using the same material over and over again? Combine them!
Same applies for textures.
There's also a note adding when pointless to do so: "*Note: using different shaders will increase draw calls, so use as many of the same type of shader to get the best results!*"

So long story short, combine identical meshes (IMHO all of them in a single scene), as long as you don't do anything else for optimization (e.g. [Occlusion Culling](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/OcclusionCulling.html)), otherwise combine one item and test the results.

Comment: But is it in any way better to combine same meshes together? Because it seems that it just makes one big mesh of them all(not uses only one). I understand why it should be done with shaders, but I don't get why type of mesh matters in any way. Also I'm wondering if using too big mesh would be pointless and affect performance in bad way?

Comment: Between us, I wouldn't do this with meshes. IMHO Occlusion Culling, lowpoly when/where needed and LOD should be more than enough. Worst case some (unbakeable, i.e. "dynamic") meshes can be turned into prefab and cached/queued. But with meshes, I wouldn't trust any "tool" override what Unity does on its own.

Comment: Thanks for advise, I'm creating game for mobile vr so performance is crucial for me.